# Problem with linq to sql transaction, head - son records

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQtoSQL.  I have two tables, one for head records, the other for rows.
Rows are connected with head record via the id of the head record in the database. To do so, I must write the head record to obtain the id and later, after inserting in the row the id of the head, I go to write rows. Clearly I must use a transaction.
But when I close the transaction, I find only head record and not the row records. Surely I made some mistakes. Can someone explain to me how to solve my problem? Thank to all.

This is the schema

```
Dim trans as Transaction.Transactionscope
Dim id as Integer

Using trans
    ' write head record
    dbase.table.insertonsubmit(head_record)
    dbase.submitchanges
    id=head_record.id

    ' insert in rows_records head_record.id
    ' write rows_records
    dbase.rowtable.insertonsubmit(row_record)

    trans.complete
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just that you are missing a submit changes

```
dim trans as transaction.transactionscope

dim id as integer

 using trans

        ' write head record

            dbase.table.insertonsubmit(head_record)

            dbase.submitchanges

            id=head_record.id

        ' insert in rows_records head_record.id
        ' write rows_records
            dbase.rowtable.insertonsubmit(row_record)

          dbase.submitchanges

 trans.complete

end using
```